# How to eat a sundae to get a good mix?

Tags: food

Twice in the last month,I have found myself battling with an ice cream sundae. The problem is that the sundae itself is served in a tall thin glass with the cream on top,then the layers of ice cream,marshmallows and syrup.

This means when you come to eat it,you end up instead of a nice mix,you get all the cream,then all the icecream,then finally at the bottom,spoonfuls of syrup.

If I try to use the long narrow spoon to mix it in the glass,it ends up pouring out the sides and going everywhere.
So is there an optimum way to get to eat my sundae neatly without creating a colossal mess at the table?

Comment: Could you request a larger container or a bowl?

Answer (score 1):

Order your sundae in a bowl or larger container more manageable for your style. Not all sundaes are "Towering Ice Cream Sundaes" served in a tall "parfait glass" which you describe.

The parfait glass is popular for serving Ice Cream Sundaes but it came from a French tradition of serving frozen custard in the tall glass with the long-handled parfait spoon.

Here are [17 different Ice Cream Sundaes](http://www.therichest.com/buzz/17-ways-to-eat-an-ice-cream-sundae/). Only one is not shown in bowls and large cups.

Stop fighting with your confections and enjoy yourself.